# FB.logout doesn't log out

Tags: facebook, authentication, logout

I have implemented a Facebook based login.
The FB.login works perfectly, but the **FB.logout** doesn't. I have tried with different FB.init, deleting cookies, running the logout page several times in a row, but the only way to log my user out is in facebook itself.

The code I'm using for logout is:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>

  FB.init({
    appId: '***************',
    xfbml: true,
    status: true,
    cookie: true
  });

  FB.getLoginStatus();

  FB.logout();
</script>
```

Any ideas?
Thank you

Comment: you also need to destroy the session in php it can be done by `session_destroy();`

Comment: Thanks. Do you know the asp equivalent?

Comment: Tried session_destroy() and session_unset() and still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

did you tried having some button onclick event is FB.logout();

```
function logout(){
     FB.logout(function(response) {
        // user is now logged out
     });
 }

  <button onclick="logout()">LogOut</button>
```

Try This

Comment: Thanks for your help. It actually worked!
I was convinced I needed the FB.init in order to run FB.logout. Apparenty not.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>
```

and then call the FB.logout(). FB must be initializad before.

From the documentation:

> This code loads the SDK asynchronously so it does not block loading other elements of your page. This is particularly important to ensure fast page loads for users and SEO robots.
>
> The URLs in the above code are protocol relative. This lets the browser to load the SDK over the same protocol (HTTP or HTTPS) as the containing page, which will prevent "Insecure Content" warnings.
>
> The function assigned to window.fbAsyncInit is run as soon as the SDK is loaded. Any code that you want to run after the SDK is loaded should be placed within this function and after the call to FB.init. For example, this is where you would test the logged in status of the user or subscribe to any Facebook events in which your application is interested.